# error to upload to images with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload two images with php. And add them to the database. Somehow it only uploads one image and the records in the database always have the same values.

this is the code i use

```
<?php
include "../connect.php";

$name1 = $_FILES['pic1']['name'];
$size1 = $_FILES['pic1']['size'];

$name2 = $_FILES['pic2']['name'];
$size3 = $_FILES['pic2']['size'];
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{

    $extension1 = pathinfo($name1,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $array = array('png','gif','jpeg','jpg');
       if (!in_array($extension1,$array)){
            echo "<div class='faild'>".$array[0]."-".$array[1]."-".$array[2]."-".$array[3]." --> (".$name.")</div>";
       }else if ($size>10000000){
            echo "<div class='faild'>Size</div>";
       }else {
            $new_image1 = time().'.'.$extension1;
            $file1 = "images/upload";
            $pic1 = "$file1/".$new_image1;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic1"]["tmp_name"],"../".$pic1."");
                             $insert = mysql_query("update temp set pic='$pic1' ") or die("error ins");    
         }

     $extension2 = pathinfo($name2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $array = array('png','gif','jpeg','jpg');
       if (!in_array($extension2,$array)){
            echo "<div class='faild'>".$array[0]."-".$array[1]."-".$array[2]."-".$array[3]." --> (".$name.")</div>";
       }else if ($size>10000000){
            echo "<div class='faild'>Size</div>";
       }else {
            $new_image2 = time().'.'.$extension2;
            $file2 = "images/upload";
            $pic2 = "$file2/".$new_image2;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic2"]["tmp_name"],"../".$pic2."");   

                      $insert = mysql_query("update temp set passport='$pic2'") or die("error ins");
             }





}
?>
```

Comment: A: That's because you don't have a `WHERE` clause and is updating your entire db.

Comment: you also need to get into the habit of accepting answers. People think your other questions are still unsolved. Good luck with this, I told you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems you have is with your update statement. There is no 'where' statement saying which record in the database should be updated so this query updates them all. That's why you only have the last image in all the database rows.

Besides that, your code is not very good from a security point of view. You should take a look at mysqli or pdo for your database connection and queries because MySQL is deprecated and removed from PHP. Also take a look at SQL injections and data validation. Besides some very basic extension and size validation there is nothing there to keep things save. Try escaping and validating all user inputs.

And another point would be to take a look at 'functions'. You're running almost the exact same piece of code at least twice. And every code change has to be done twice. Perfect for a function call, something like

```
function storeImage($image){
    // write the uploading and storing PHP here
}
```

Comment: it's only one record on data base and i only want to update it , so please could you help me more and tell me what's the problem

Comment: I told you what the problem is. Just as - Fred ii - did in the comments on your questions. Add where statements to your update function